# PySpark/SQL joining on non unique key

Tags: sql, join, pyspark

I have two transaction tables that I need to join; however, there's no clean link between these two tables:

For t1 I have:

```
unique_id | date | units
```

for t2 I have:

```
unique_id | date | store_id | transaction_key
```

My desired output is to get units in terms of store_id; when I do a left join on t1 with unique_id and date, however, there are cases where customers make multiple transactions on the same day which gives me duplicates on transaction key.

Sample data and output added:

Table 1 and table 2:

[image: Table 1 and table 2]

Current output:

[image: Current output]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: @GMB Hey GMB, added. Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Is the "Current output" from a SQL query? If so, can readers see it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a `left join`, but with `row_number()` as a matching condition:

```
select t1.unique_id, t1.date, t1.units, t2.store_id, t2.transaction_key
from (
    select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by unique_id, date order by units) rn
    from table1 t1
) t1
left join (
    select t2.*, row_number() over(partition by unique_id, date order by transaction_key) rn
    from table2 t2
) t2
    on t2.unique_id = t.unique_id and t2.date = t1.date and t2.rn = t1.rn
```